# How to set a field different from id as primary key in django rest model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to django_rest framework and I am having a problem with setting another field as primary key and then use that field as foreign key in another model.
These are my models:

```
class Test(models.Model):
 
     test_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="A10", primary_key=True)
     issue_date = models.DateField() 
     total_amount = models.FloatField(max_length=50, default=1.0)


class AnotherModel(models.Model):

     test_identifier = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #The identifier
     refered_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

But when I try to create an AnotherModel in admin page it shows this error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/api/anothertest/add/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

My question is how can I make the test_id primary key and use it as foreign in second model?

Comment: If you just wanna pass through that, add `db_constraint=False` to your model relationship: `test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False)`.

Comment: It is showing the same error again, with db_constraint=False added.

Comment: Okay, to achieve that, I removed primary_key=True from test_id field and added unique=True, and then added on my serializer class this line:
test_identifier = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='test_id', read_only=True) and now the  "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" is gone.